# Can we integrate Mocha testing and TestRail?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, npm-scripts, testrail

So, I am building an application. It's an Node JS application, tested using Mocha + Chai + NPM Selenium, and also have TestRail to log test cases. So what I want is, I want to build a test plan in TestRail using the selected Test Cases, and fetch them in my app when I perform `npm run test`and run only those cases.

For example, I build a test plan whose id is "X123", then I run the command like `npm run test --X123` and then it only run those tests that I specifically selected in my plan.

No leads, so far of my research